# Laravel event not being Broadcast

Tags: laravel, events, vue.js, laravel-echo

I am working on a chat/message feature for an app. When a User sends a message, I want a specific Event to be triggered and to be broadcasted. I am then wanting Laravel Echo to listen on the event's broadcast channel to an event via Laravel Echo, using the `pusher` driver.

I am wanting the Laravel Echo implementation to be in a Vue component and to retrieve the data that was broadcasted via the event. Currently, I can't get an event to broadcast to either a private channel or just a channel.

Here is what I have done:

1) Added the config to `.env`.

2) Added config to `bootstrap.js` :

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: 'mykey',
  encypted: false
});
```

3) Added auth check in `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider` (just returning true if User is signed in for now):

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
  // verify that user is recipient of message
  return \Auth::check();
});
```

4) Added `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,` to `App/config/app.php`.

5) Created the Event `App\Events\UserSentMessage`, which broadcasts on a `PrivateChannel` named `chat`. I have also tried to broadcast to a `Channel`. I checked and the event is being fired from a call to the `event()` helper in a controller, it just seems to not be broadcast. I have also tried using the `broadcast` method in the controller mentioned.

6) Added the following within the `mounted` Vue life cycle hook in a valid Vue component (component is rendering data etc as expected, just not working with Laravel Echo atm):

```
    Echo.private('chat').listen('UserSentMessage', (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            }, (e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
```

Have also tried:

```
     Echo.channel('chat').listen('UserSentMessage', (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            }, (e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
```

The Vue component is successfully subscribing to the channel specified. The pusher debug console recognized that it is being subscribed to, but the Event, when triggered never gets broadcasted.

Seems to be that there is a problem with broadcasting the event. I have also tried using the `broadcast()` helper, rather than the `event()` helper.

Also, when subscribing to the event with Laravel Echo via `Echo.private()`. It seems to prefix the channel name with `private`, so I have also tried broadcasting (in the event) to a channel named `private-chat`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I can recommend You to check Your `.env` file 
and make sure `BROADCAST_DRIVER` is not `log` (try `pusher`) 
and also don't forget to keep running queue listener:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

UPD.: if You look for more advanced solution, read about [laravel horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/horizon)

Comment: After pulling my hair for hours you saved my day. I did not realize it was all being stacked up in the queue. Thanks!!

Comment: @StoneyEagle happy to know that my answer was helpful

Comment: Hi, please why do i have to run `php artisan queue:listen`

Comment: @MamadouHadyBarry from command line. MacOS, Linux: terminal, Windows: cmd or power shell

Comment: @MamadouHadyBarry as an example watch this: https://youtu.be/EZqNu9Bqp7w

Answer (score 6):

the event will not be broadcasted immediately, it will be send to the queue, only when you listen or work on the queue, the event will be consumed. If you want execute jobs immediately, set QUEUE_DRIVER=sync . see: [laravel queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, my event class file is generated by "make:event", it does have `broadcastOn` method... But have no `implements ShouldBroadcast`~
It causes the laravel-echo-server output nothing~

Laravel Framework 8.13.0

Answer (score 1):

I have upvoted Num8er's reply but i also found some other issues so maybe they can help you too.

1) Remove all 'private-' from the beginning of your channel names. These get handled behind the scenes by the various libraries (eg socket.io/laravel-echo). If you look at any debug output you will see 'private-' prepended to the front of the channel names but you DO NOT need to add these.

2) If you're using redis then make sure the REDIS_PREFIX is set to an empty string in your .env file. By default it's set to something like 'laravel_database' and this messes up the channel names.

```
REDIS_PREFIX=
```

3) Make sure you've got your laravel-echo server running (and redis/pusher). Also you need to make sure you have the queue worker running:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

4) It's worth enabling debugging output on your Echo Server as this will tell you useful info about traffic (eg channel names) so modify the laravel-echo-server.json file (in your project root dir) so that devMode is set to true:

```
"devMode": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

@materliu: that was a good hint. In my case i did not create a queue with the working directory set to the project i am working on. Using circus. The event was triggered in code but no job listener was available. As soon as i run "php artisan queue:listen" suddenly all previous broadcasts have been processed.

Usually its difficult to figure out which component of a complex system does not work.